# Iterate with loop through excel sheet and store values in variables using Python

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was trying to read dats from excel sheet using python, due to some constraints i'm not able to use external libraries. I'm doing it with from Microsoft.Office.Interop import Excel. Now I'm able to read the datas from sheet by defining them explicitly. like,

```
x1=ws.Rows[3].Value2[0,0]
y1=ws.Rows[3].Value2[0,1]
z1=ws.Rows[3].value2[0,2]

x2=ws.Rows[4].value2[0,0]
y2=ws.Rows[4].value2[0,1]
z2=ws.Rows[4].value2[0,2]

x3=ws.Rows[5].value2[0,0]
y3=ws.Rows[5].value2[0,1]
z3=ws.Rows[5].value2[0,2]

x4=ws.Rows[6].value2[0,0]
y4=ws.Rows[6].value2[0,1]
z4=ws.Rows[6].value2[0,2]
```

But I want to loop it. How to loop it? at the end i need values in variables.

Comment: You might want to look at the concept of nested loops to solve this problem. By the way, the first two rows you have Value2 and after that you have value2. This may cause an error depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are reading a fixed number of 3 values for each row, I would recommend to use 3 lists for x, y, and z as a data structure:

```
x = []
y = []
z = []
for row in ws.Rows[3:]:
    x.append(row.Value2[0,0])
    y.append(row.Value2[0,1])
    z.append(row.Value2[0,2])
```

Then you can access your values via `x[0]`, `z[4]` etc.

If the number of columns is also variable, you should use a [2D array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/) and two nested for loops for assigning the values.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to declare the variables in the described way you could use, here you will get the 5 first x,y,z positions from your excel:

```
for i in range(5):
    globals()['x{0}'.format(i)] = ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,0]
    globals()['y{0}'.format(i)] = ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,1]
    globals()['z{0}'.format(i)] = ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,2]
```

I however would recommend storing the points in a list of dictionary like this:

```
positions = list()
for i in range(5):
    positions.append({
        'x': ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,0]
        'y': ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,1]
        'z': ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,2]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
led = []
for i in range(5):
    globals()['x' + 'i'] = ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,0]
    globals()['y' + 'i'] = ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,1]
    globals()['z' + 'i'] = ws.Rows[i + 2].Value2[0,2]
    led.append(globals()['x' + 'i'])
    led.append(globals()['y' + 'i'])
    led.append(globals()['z' + 'i'])
```

It worked for me,as per my requirements.